# Who to access at properties of a file using js

Tags: javascript, html

Could any one help me with the steps to getting the properties of a file like name path size and more using JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one will help you to understand the basics: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/name

So once you have the file object you can read its properties (name,size,type,lastModified,lastModifiedDate), in your case its name.